# Must an infinite intersection of infinite sets be infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinity

If $A_2$ is a subset of $A_1$, $A_3$ is a subset of $A_2$, and this goes on infinitely and all contain an infinite number of elements, then is the intersection from $n=1$ to infinity, infinite as well? Prove if no.

Answer (score 14):

The answer to your question is no; infact, the intersection can easily be $\emptyset$. If we define $A_i = (0,1/i)$ for $ i \in \mathbb{N}$, then we have that

$$ A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset \cdots $$

yet

$$ \bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i = \emptyset $$

despite all the $A_i$ have uncountably many elements. As Peter's comment says, we have that the proposition is false even if we just consider countable sets.

Comment: The uncountability is unnecessary. One can do just as well with countable sets: take $A_i = \{ x \in \mathbb{N}\ |\ x > i \}$.

Comment: What would the intersection from Peter's be equal to?

Comment: @Sydney Think what it means for something to be in the intersection of a number of sets, and then from that consider what happens if you assume there is something in the infinite intersection.

Comment: but $A_\inf$ doesn't have infinite elements?? because $1/\inf$ is $0$, so  interval (0,0) only has one element viz. 0?

Answer (score 4):

An example already appears here, but maybe this one is for some purposes simpler.  Consider the sets $\{n,n+1,n+2,n+3,\ldots\}$.  Their intersection is
$$
\{1,2,3,4,5,6,\ldots\}\cap\{2,3,4,5,6,\ldots\}\cap\{3,4,5,6,\ldots\}\cap\{4,5,6,\ldots\}\cap\cdots\cdots.
$$
This set is empty.

Another example: Consider the set of all intervals $(0,x)$, where $x>0$.  Their intersection is empty.

<s>Another example: Suppose one of the infinitely many sets is the set of all even numbers, and another is the set of all odd numbers.  What the others are besides those two, we don't need to know in order to see that the intersection of all of them is empty.</s>

Comment: if $A_{1}$ is the set of all even numbers and $A_{2}$ is the set of all odd numbers, doesn't this violate the condition that $A_{2}$ be a subset of $A_{1}$, as the question states?

Comment: @FakeBrain : Yes. It seems by the time I reached that point I had forgotten that condition.